# Patch 32bit executable to use 3Gb RAM in 64bit Windows

Tags: python, memory, patch

I am having an issue where my 32bit python.exe (version 2.3, yes, ancient!) is failing as the exeuction exceeds 2Gb of RAM.

I understand that one solution is to compile python from source, with the large memory support flag set.

However, I've seen patches online, similar to this, 
http://www.ntcore.com/4gb_patch.php

Would you recommend this?  I tested it on my desktop, and it does allow me up to 3Gb of memory.

Have anyone used this?  Is it stable?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: work expands to occupy the space available to it, and then some. if you give your app 3gig, you'll eventually want 4gig, then 5gig... why not just ugprade to a 64bit python and essentially eliminate the ram limit?

Comment: It might work. It might not. Has anyone audited the Python 2.3 source, and all your extensions, for large address aware issues?

Comment: Forgot to mentioned, that upgrading python is no an option.  We are relying on a .dll, which could only be imported by python 2.3 :(

Comment: The python installation we are using was downloading from python in binaries.  So all stock standard.  Could not find python 2.3 source code, hence looking at binary patches.